# No such namespace: quil.helpers.seqs

Tags: clojurescript, leiningen, quil

I am learning ClojureScript by playing around with Quil. When I attempted to implement [this Quil example](https://github.com/quil/quil-examples/blob/master/src/quil_sketches/gen_art/05_random_scribble.clj) in ClojureScript, I got the error message:  `No such namespace: quil.helpers.seqs`.

The error can be reproduced by creating a new project with lein: `lein new quil-cljs quil-helpers` and attempting to use a function from `quil.helpers.seqs` in the `core.cljs` file.

Why am I getting this error?

Here's the `core.cljs` file where I attempt to use a function from this namespace:

```clj
(ns quil-helpers.core
  (:require [quil.core :as q :include-macros true]
            [quil.helpers.seqs :as s]
            [quil.middleware :as m]))

(defn draw [state]
  (s/range-incl 0 10)
  (q/background 200)
  (q/ellipse 200 200 100 100))

(defn ^:export run-sketch []
  (q/defsketch quil-helpers
    :host "quil-helpers"
    :size [500 500]
    :draw draw
    :middleware [m/fun-mode]))
```

Here's the project.clj file generated by lein:

```clj
(defproject quil-helpers "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write description"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.10.1"]
                 [quil "3.1.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "1.10.520"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.1.7"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.5.19"]]
  :hooks [leiningen.cljsbuild]

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js"]
  :cljsbuild
  {:builds [; development build with figwheel hot swap
            {:id "development"
             :source-paths ["src"]
             :figwheel true
             :compiler
             {:main "quil_helpers.core"
              :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
              :output-dir "resources/public/js/development"
              :asset-path "js/development"}}
            ; minified and bundled build for deployment
            {:id "optimized"
             :source-paths ["src"]
             :compiler
             {:main "quil_helpers.core"
              :output-to "resources/public/js/main.js"
              :output-dir "resources/public/js/optimized"
              :asset-path "js/optimized"
              :optimizations :advanced}}]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see [in the repo](https://github.com/quil/quil/blob/master/src/clj/quil/helpers/seqs.clj), `quil.helpers.seqs` is a CLJ namespace - you can't use it just like that in CLJS. But no idea why it's a CLJ NS - doesn't seem like there's anything JVM-specific, so maybe it's worth creating a feature request.